# Program to check if in line are doubled words

Tags: python

I made program to open a text file and count the number of lines without doubled words. This number is printed in the end.

This is an example text file:

```
sayndz zfxlkl attjtww cti sokkmty brx fhh suelqbp
xmuf znkhaes pggrlp zia znkhaes znkhaes
nti rxr bogebb zdwrin
sryookh unrudn zrkz jxhrdo zrkz
bssqn wbmdc rigc zketu ketichh enkixg bmdwc stnsdf jnz mqovwg ixgken
```

I've already made a program, and it looks like that program works. But I'm aware that in programming if something works it doesn't mean that program is made properly.

My code:

```
class SkyphrasesValidation(object):
    def get_text_file(self):
        file = open('C:/Users/PC/Documents/skychallenge_skyphrase_input.txt', 'r')
        return file

    def lines_list(self):
        text = self.get_text_file()
        line_list = text.readlines()
        return [line.split() for line in line_list]

    def phrases_validation(self):
        validated_phrases = 0
        for line in self.lines_list():
            new_line = []
            for word in line:
                exam = line.count(word)
                if exam > 1:
                    new_line.append(0)
                else:
                    new_line.append(1)
            if 0 in new_line:
                validated_phrases += 0
            else:
                validated_phrases += 1
        return validated_phrases

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phrases_validation())

text = SkyphrasesValidation()

print(text)
```

Is my logic good and is this program is well-made? Or maybe it looks like poop and I could write this more clearly?

Comment: When you say "doubled words" do you mean the same word immediately repeated, like "the the" or do you mean a line that contains the same word twice, possibly with words in between, like "if I could I would"?

Comment: I mean that in one line are 2 or even more same words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

### Keep file handlers in one function.

First off, the `get_text_file()` and `lines_list()` methods:

> ```
> def get_text_file(self):
>     file = open('C:/Users/PC/Documents/skychallenge_skyphrase_input.txt', 'r')
>     return file
>
> def lines_list(self):
>     text = self.get_text_file()
>     line_list = text.readlines()
>     return [line.split() for line in line_list]
> ```

1. It's generally a bad idea to pass files outside of a function... it poses some questions: Who will close the file? When? And how? Instead, *open and close it in the same function* so that the file can be *contained*.
2. Since the `lines_list()` method is only reading text off from `get_text_file()` (and nothing else), it may be better to simply write *one* function which reads handles and reads lines off the file. (The splitting of lines, `line.split()`, can be done in `phrases_validation()`.)

With these points in mind, we could define `get_text_lines()` as:

```
def get_text_lines(self):
    with open('C:/Users/PC/Documents/skychallenge_skyphrase_input.txt', 'r') as file:
        line_list = file.readlines()

    return line_list
```

Notice that the use of the [`with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for). This automatically closes the file when the block-scope is exited.

Using the above function implies modifying `phrases_validation()`:

```
def phrases_validation(self):
    # ...
    for line in get_text_lines():   # call function here
        # ...
        words = line.split()        # split lines here
        for word in words:          # iterate through split line here
            # ...
```

### The Validation Algorithm

I've tried annotating the meat of your `phrases_validation`:

> ```
> # iterate through lines...
> for line in get_text_lines():
>
>     new_line = []  # container to store 1s and 0s
>
>     # iterate through words...
>     words = line.split()
>     for word in words:
>
>         exam = line.count(word)
>
>         # append 0 if word is duplicated
>         if exam > 1:
>             new_line.append(0)
>
>         # append 1 if word is not duplicated
>         else:
>             new_line.append(1)
>
>     # increment validated_phrases if no duplicates
>     if 0 in new_line:
>         validated_phrases += 0
>     else:
>         validated_phrases += 1
> ```

Some general suggestions:

1. Opt for readability. Since only `0` and `1` are being used, this implies a *binary* domain, and thus can be substituted with `False` and `True` respectively.
2. `validated_phrases += 0` This can be removed since nothing is added. Simply do

   ```
   if 0 not in new_line:
       validated_phrases += 1
   ```

Some possible improvements to the algorithm:

#### Using the `any` built-in function.

The `any` built-in function takes a list and tests for truth. If any of the elements are [*Truthy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), `any` returns `True`, else `False`. Your inner loop can make use of the `any` function:

```
for line in get_text_lines():
    words = line.split()

    has_duplicates = any(words.count(word) > 1 for word in words)
    if not has_duplicates:
        validated_phrases += 1
```

Here, a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) was used: `words.count(word) > 1 for word in words`.

This generates an iterable of `True`/`False` values: `True` if `words.count(word) > 1` and `False` otherwise. We then check whether there are any duplicates and if not, increment `validated_phrases`.

(To keep track of the number of duplicates, you can use the `sum` function instead. This will add the `True` values, counting the number of duplicates.)

#### Using the `set` class.

Indeed, there are a couple more ways to check for duplicates. `list.count` has a time-complexity with an upper-bound of \$O(n)\$ (with \$n\$ being the length of the list), i.e. it searches the entire list, which may be slow when the list grows to sizes of thousands or millions.

One other way to check for duplicates would be to obtain a container of *unique* words, and check whether it has the same length as the list of words in the line. We can use `set` to obtain the unique words.

```
for line in get_text_lines():
    words = line.split()

    unique_words = set(words)
    has_duplicates = len(unique_words) != len(words)
    if not has_duplicates:
        validated_phrases += 1,
```

I'm not entirely sure about the complexity of `set(words)` but [the `len` function has a time complexity of \$O(1)\$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115313/cost-of-len-function) which can be *really fast* in the long run.

#### Using the `collections.Counter` class.

Another way that might be of interest would be to use `Counter` from the `collections` module.

```
for line in get_text_lines():
    words = line.split()

    counter = Counter(words)
    has_duplicates = any(counter[word] != 1 for word in counter)
    if not has_duplicates:
        validated_phrases += 1
```

<sup>*(For this, remember to add `from collections import Counter` at the top of your script.)*</sup>

### Try not to rely on `__str__`.

In your code, the main algorithm, `phrases_validation()`, is only called when `str(text)` or `text__str__()` is called (this is implicitly called by `print(text)`).

It's creative... but prefer to directly call `phrases_validation()`:

```
validator = SkyphrasesValidation()
print(validator.phrases_validation())
```

(And call `str()` on it if needed.) This is more explicit to readers that you're calling the `phrases_validation()` method.

Generally, the `__str__` magic method should be overloaded when you're trying to display a class' members contents. Unfortunately, `SkyphrasesValidation` doesn't have any members.

The variable name `text` can be interpreted in several ways. Is it a text file? A string?  Consider a more descriptive name instead. (`validator` was used in the example above.)

### Class?

The class could have been substituted with one/two functions. But sticking with a class... since the `self` argument is rarely used, consider making the methods [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) or instead, place `get_text_lines()` *outside* of the class and pass the lines of text to `phrases_validation()` as an argument.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There are a lot of good suggestions in this answer, unfortunately bracketed by some ungood language. You might want to read the [Code of Conduct](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/conduct) again, and be a bit more friendly.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful, I closed all program in one function

Comment: @AustinHastings Hmm, okay. I've tried to tidy the answer some more. I'll try to catch hold of my fingers before typing next time. Thanks for the tip!